# 7 Segment Display with VHDL

Tags: logic, vhdl

I am currently working with vhdl and am having trouble with a 7 Segment display. I found this code online and am having trouble understand what it exactly means. Could some help me understand what is going on with the following code:

```
ARCHITECTURE Structure OF multi IS
 SIGNAL C : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
 LEDR <= SW;
 C(2 DOWNTO 0) <= SW(2 DOWNTO 0);

 HEX0(0) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) ); 
 HEX0(1) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) ); 
 HEX0(2) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) ); 
 HEX0(3) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND NOT(C(0))) OR
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) ); 
 HEX0(4) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND NOT(C(0))) OR (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) );
 HEX0(5) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR 
 (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) OR
 (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND NOT(C(0))) OR (NOT(C(2)) AND C(1) AND C(0)) ); 
 HEX0(6) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR
 (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) );
END Structure;
```

I do not understand the logic in all the NOT and OR statements.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens when code escapes online from an Obfuscated VHDL contest.

Or perhaps being more charitable, someone junior was handed an early 1970s schematic for an octal-to-7-segment decoder chip (or circuit board!), and asked to rewrite it in VHDL because the original components are no longer available. He/she has written it out in classic "sum of products" form and not attempted to minimise it...

I believe the best thing you can do is to write out the whole thing as a lookup table, bit by bit, and not worry about the details of the logic.

Start with each expression...

```
 HEX0(6) <= NOT( (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND NOT(C(0))) OR
 (NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)) AND C(0)) );
```

And minimise it

```
 HEX0(6) <= NOT((NOT(C(2)) AND NOT(C(1)));
```

And write it out for each value

```
C  C2  C1  C0  H6  H5  H4  H3  H2  H1  H0   HEX0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0001001 = 09
1   0   0   1   0
2   0   1   0   1
3   0   1   1   1
4   1   0   0   1
5   1   0   1   1
6   1   1   0   1
7   1   1   1   1
```

(Not complete and not guaranteed correct either...)

Then rewrite the thing along these lines:

```
subtype Seven_Seg is std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

constant Lookup : array(0 to 7) of Seven_Seg := ( 0 => "0001001",
                                                  1 => ...
                                                  ...
                                                  7 => ... );

Hex0 <= Lookup(to_integer(unsigned(C)));
```

and be done with it.